# Convergence of a finite series on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals

If I have output values of a signal $y$ (or series) stored in a $1\times N$ matrix, where $N$ is finite. Is there any MATLAB code or function I can use to determine if the signal converges or diverges?

Comment: Hello. What do you mean with "the signal converges or diverges"? If the signal only has a finite number of samples $N$, how do you define convergence?

Comment: If N is large enough, we can decide if the series converges without going to infinity.

Comment: Can I interpret the question as: Let's say we have a series of values $ {x}_{n} $. Assuming we have a machine to generate those to any given $ n $. Can we have some test on this finite set of numbers to say something about the convergence of $ {x}_{n} $ when $ n $ goes to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

To confidently determine convergence, you should always test for meeting a formal convergence criteria.

As a hack, you can numerically calculate the series until it "stops moving" or your running out of time/memory or start getting NaNs, infinites or over/underflows.

Answer (score 0):

In short: (see below for details)

- yes in practice, there are quantities often called stopping criteria, developed for instance in optimization to stop an iterative algorithm considered to be convergent (eg [How to determine stopping criteria in iterative methods?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/187936/257503)). Yet:
- yes again, because any finite series is convergent, by nature,
- but no, no measure can really predict converge, especially in machine learning or  deep neural networks, where double or multiple descent can be observed,
- and some fine bits can be found in a recent relevant post by Terence Tao: [Soft analysis, hard analysis and the finite convergence principle](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/soft-analysis-hard-analysis-and-the-finite-convergence-principle).

From a mathematical point of view, **a finite series  is convergent**, as answered on [Can a sequence be called convergent/divergent if it has finite number of terms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/600804/257503).

If it is a subsequence of an infinite series, I know of no way to tell for sure from the subsequence   that the whole sequence convergence. There are many counter-examples and reasons: processes that stay still over some horizon and suddenly rise, computational errors  that accumulate until the system becomes unstable. There is even a recent phenomenon called "double descent" in machine learning or deep networks: in [Deep Double Descent](https://openai.com/blog/deep-double-descent/) one can read:

> We show that the double descent phenomenon occurs in CNNs, ResNets,
> and transformers: performance first improves, then gets worse, and
> then improves again with increasing model size, data size, or training
> time [illustrated below]

[image: Deep double descent with model size]

The message is that we can always have surprises when it comes to guess the end of a graph.
However, in the optimization literature, there is a need to stop algorithms at some iteration, using the shape of some empirical loss function. They are typically computed from absolute or relative differences between consecutive values of iterates. A couple of examples are given in [How to test convergence of an algorithm for constrained optimization](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/14286/19501).

Comment: I think the point of the question was totally different. Let's say we have a series of values $ {x}_{n} $. Let's say we have a machine to generate those to any given $ n $. Can we have some test on this finite set of numbers to say something about the convergence of $ {x}_{n} $ when $ n $ goes to infinity?